# OpenUI5: TypeError: this.getAutoPrefixId is not a function

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm writing a tiny app on OpenUI5+NodeJS. When I call `index.html` I've got the following error in browser's console: `TypeError: this.getAutoPrefixId is not a function`. Top part of stacktrace is following:

```
init sap-ui-core.js line 175  
init Component.js:19  
constructor ManagedObject-dbg.js:444  
constructor ManagedObject-dbg.js:463  
constructor Component-dbg.js:244
```

Line `init Component.js:19` is from my `Component.js`: `UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);`
Please help.

Regards, Lev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `init` function was declared in that way: `init => () {}`. After convering it to a regular function (I mean `init: function (){}`) everything became fine.